# How to make a number increasingly larger

Tags: java

I'm making a level/XP system and I want the XP to have larger gaps in between levels over time. But everything that I can think of and have tried keeps the same gap in between levels. Example: `300...600...900...1200...etc.` and what I want is something like `300...600...1000...2000...3200...etc.`

Currently, this is how I get a result like the first example.

```
private static final double BASE_LEVEL_UP_ADJUSTMENT = 1.5;
private static final int BASE_LEVEL_EXP = 200;

public static void main(String... args) {
    int currentLevel;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        currentLevel = i;
        System.out.println("Level " + currentLevel + " Exp: " + getNextLevelExp(currentLevel));
    }
}

public static double getNextLevelExp(int currentLevel) {
    return (BASE_LEVEL_EXP * currentLevel * BASE_LEVEL_UP_ADJUSTMENT);
}
```

I have figured out why I keep getting the first example, but I can't figure out how to get something like the second example. It's probably super simple, but I can't figure it out. Any help is always appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the difference between a linear function and an exponential function?

Comment: @JosephSible That's what I've been trying to think of! I knew I kept getting a linear line, but I couldn't figure out how to create a "curved" one in a sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
import java.lang.Math;

class Playground {
private static final double BASE_LEVEL_UP_ADJUSTMENT = 2;
private static final int BASE_LEVEL_EXP = 200;

public static void main(String... args) {
    int currentLevel;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        currentLevel = i;
        System.out.println("Level " + currentLevel + " Exp: " + getNextLevelExp(currentLevel));
    }
}

public static double getNextLevelExp(int currentLevel) {
    return (BASE_LEVEL_EXP * Math.pow(currentLevel, BASE_LEVEL_UP_ADJUSTMENT));
}
}
```